# How Do I scroll into view on button click and show iframe at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that when clicked I show an iframe, I want to scroll into the iframe so when the iframe loads after a button cliked I don't have to scroll to view the iframe instead it does that for me. I've tried this approach

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bpbutton").click(function() {
    document.getElementById("iframe1").src="http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_src.asp";
        $("#iframe1").slideDown();
        document.getElementById("iframe1").scrollIntoView();
    });
});
```

But after I click the button it shows the iframe, then I have to click again to get it to scroll into the view. I can't seem to get it to do both at the same time??

Comment: Try putting the scrollIntoView() function call inside a callback to slideDown(). e.g. `$('#iframe').slideDown(function(){document.getElementById("iframe1").scrollIntoView();})`

Comment: tried `$("#iframe1").slideDown(document.getElementById("iframe1").scrollIntoView());` I still have to click once for iframe to show then click again for scroll into view to work.